# Limit of an increasing sequence of probability measures is a probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let {$P_{n}$} be a sequence of probabilities on a $\sigma$-field $F$ satisfying $P_{n}(A)$ $\le$ $P_{n+1}(A)$ for all $A$ and $n$. Define $P(A) =  sup P_{n}(A)$ for each $A$ in $F$. Is $P$ a probability measure?

Comment: Anyway, such a sequence satisfies $P=P_n$ for all $n$. That is because for any $A\in F$ we have $P_{n+1}(A)\geq P_n(A)=1-P_n(A^c)\geq 1-P_{n+1}(A^c)=P_{n+1}(A).$

Comment: Sorry, what? How?

Comment: For more general measures, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Recall that any monoton and bounded sequence is convergent. That is for any $A$ there exists a P(A) such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}P_n(A)=P(A)=\sup P_n(A).$$

We have to prove that $P$ is a probability measure on the measurable space $[\Omega,\mathcal A]$ on which the $P_n$s are probability measures. $0\le P\le1$ for any $A\in \mathcal A$ and $P(\emptyset)=0$. It remains to demonstrate that for any countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets $\{A_n\}$

$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n).$$

Now

$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\lim_{m\to \infty}P_m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_m(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{m\to \infty}P_m(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n).$$

Comment: Why did you discuss the limit and not the upper limit?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: We have monoton and bounded sequences.

Comment: So if you were to change the question to general mesures, you would get just an outer measure? Or would it still be a measure?

Comment: Can the limit and the summation in the last sentence of the proof be changed that easily? Wouldn't there be some conditions for that?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Perhaps. To be honest, I don't know that for the time being . Have to think. (For finite measures everything is OK, I guess that for $\sigma$ finite measure : yes, again. But for extended valued measures! I don't know. The bounded convergence argument would be missed. )